# How do I get std::weak_ptr<MyClass> from this pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, this, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Here is the example:

```
tempalate <class T> class MyClass : public T {
    public: 
    MyClass(std::weak_ptr<MyClass> parent) {
         //--------------------------------------+
         //                                      |
         //                                      V
         auto child = std::make_shared<MyClass>(this);
    }
};
```

How to do that? If I need to derive `MyClass` from `std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass<T>>`, how do I do that without multiple inheritance, since `MyClass` already derived from another `T` ancestor, and I need to call `shared_from_this()` on constructor?

In my case `T` could be some class inherited from `enable_shared_from_this<T>`, but not always

Comment: Multiple inheritance is the correct answer. I don't see why it is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`std::enable_shared_from_this` does not inherit from T, so there's no problem here.

you don't need to call `shared_from_this` in the CTor, you would call that when you have `this`and need the respective `shared_ptr`.

Comment: the problem is T could be inherited from `std::enable_shared_from_this` too, is it OK? because i'am a little afraid

Comment: Ah ok - I tried your scenario, that seems to be problematic (using std:.tr1 of VS2008). You might be able to use `enable_if` to prevent inheritance (or inherit another dummy) if T already inherits from enable_shared_from_this. However, I'm not fluent enough with these metatemplatery to try it out.